# Timer runs faster every time method is called

Tags: android, performance, methods, timer, call

I have a little problem with my android application. I tried to code a timer which starts over every time I press a button. But if I do so, the timer get's faster every time the timer method is called. I have no idea, why it's doing that...

```
public void Dev(View view) {
    cube=(int) (Math.random()*6+1);
    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView.setText("Insert number: "+String.valueOf(cube));
    Button play = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button11);
    play.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    ablauf();   
}

public void ablauf() {
    //progress.cancel();
    progressStatus = 200;
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    progressBar.setMax(200);
    progressBar.setProgress(200);

    progress=new Timer();
    tasklol= new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            progressmethod();
        }
    };

    progress.scheduleAtFixedRate(tasklol, 0, 30);
}


public void progressmethod() {
    progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
    progressStatus=progressStatus-1;

    if(progressStatus<0) {
    }
}

public void stopTimers(){

    progress.cancel();




}
```

And here is a example of a Button that calls the method:

```
public void B2 (View view)
{
    if (filled2==false) {
        ablauf();
        stopTimers();
        Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setText(String.valueOf(cube));
        b=cube;
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        cube=(int) (Math.random()*6+1);
        textView.setText("Insert number: "+String.valueOf(cube));
        filled2=true;
        counter=counter+1;

        if (counter==9) {
            Berechnen(view);
            textView.setText("Press play to start");
        } else {
            ablauf();
        }
    }
}
```

It would be very nice if you could help us pleeeeeeeeeeease ;)

Comment: my guess is that you have multiple timerthreads running simultaneously. Every time ablauf() is called a new one is started

Answer (score 0):

You call the method ablauf() in a couple of places, and in that method you initialize and create a timer and a timer task, but you don't stop them correctly. Therefore, you have multiple timers running.

Comment: I did pinpoint the problem. He should stop the timer every time he's done with using it, but he doesn't.